# iOS-fail of get value

Tags: ios

I use `objectForKey` to get value from an `xml` file but not its failed. Here is parts of the `xml` data

```
{
"__name" = root;
destination = CIVC;
message =     {
    "co2_emissions" = "<p>CO<sub>2</sub> emissions saved by this BART trip: <strong>9.8 pounds.</strong> <a href=\"http://www.bart.gov/guide/carbon.aspx\">Read more</a></p>";
    legend = "bikeflag: 1 = bikes allowed. 0 = no bikes allowed. transfercode: blank = no transfer, N = normal transfer, T = timed transfer, connecting trains will wait up to five minutes for transferring passengers. S = scheduled transfer, connecting trains will not wait for transferring passengers if there is a delay.";
};
origin = ASHB;
"sched_num" = 34;
schedule =     {
    after = 2;
    before = 2;
    date = "Jan 6, 2014";
    request =         {
        trip =             (
                            {
                "_clipper" = "1.40";
                "_destTimeDate" = "01/06/2014";
                "_destTimeMin" = "11:52 AM";
                "_destination" = CIVC;
                "_fare" = "3.75";
                "_origTimeDate" = "01/06/2014 ";
                "_origTimeMin" = "11:27 AM";
                "_origin" = ASHB;
                leg =                     {
                    "_bikeflag" = 1;
                    "_destTimeDate" = "01/06/2014";
                    "_destTimeMin" = "11:52 AM";
                    "_destination" = CIVC;
                    "_line" = "ROUTE 7";
                    "_order" = 1;
                    "_origTimeDate" = "01/06/2014";
                    "_origTimeMin" = "11:27 AM";
                    "_origin" = ASHB;
                    "_trainHeadStation" = MLBR;
                    "_trainIdx" = 29;
                    "_transfercode" = "";
                };
            },
```

and here is my code to get the `origin`,`destination`, `sched_num`, `date`, `_destTimeDate
origin`, `destination`, `sched_num`, `date` work well

```
self.DepartLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"origin"];
self.ArriveLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"destination"];
self.SchednumLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"sched_num"];
self.DateLabel.text = [[dic objectForKey:@"schedule"] objectForKey:@"date"];
self.TimeLabel.text = [[[[dic objectForKey:@"schedule"] objectForKey:@"request"]objectForKey:@"trip"]objectForKey:@"_destTimeDate"];
```

Only the `_destTimeDate` doest work. How to get this value?

Comment: Please note that IOS isn't the same as iOS. IOS stands for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_IOS whilst iOS stands for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the output of your `NSDictionary` then you need to grab the first index.

```
self.TimeLabel.text = [[[[[dic objectForKey:@"schedule"] objectForKey:@"request"] objectForKey:@"trip"] objectAtIndex:0 ] objectForKey:@"_destTimeDate"];
```

or as Martin R pointed out you can do it like this as well

```
dic[@"schedule"][@"request"][@"trip"][0][@"_destTimeDate"]
```